# Unable to send traffic over RDMA

Tags: rdma

I have softROCE setup on SUSE Linux SP11. I am trying to validate the traffic over RXE device. I am able to send and receive traffic using `ibv_*_pingpong`. But for rping it is giving and error `RDMA_CM_EVENT_UNREACHABLE, error -110`.

```
#rxe_cfg -l
Name  Link  Driver  Speed  NMTU  IPv4_addr      RDEV  RMTU

p4p1  yes   r8169          1500  10.213.64.106  rxe0  1024  (3)
```

Comment: Could you provide the `rping` command lines you've used? Which version of SoftRoCE are you using?

Comment: The command that I am running is Server - " rping -svV -a 10.213.64.106 " and Client - " rping -cvV -a 10.213.64.106 ". Regarding softRoCE, I have forked https://github.com/SoftRoCE openSource project and using V2.

Comment: No, its still not fixed. Can you please share the location for the new version.